# Compare division method versus multiplication method for hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

For hashing, I would like to compare division method versus multiplication method disadvantages.

**Multiplication method**: Given that we have hash function `f(k)=⌊N×(kA−⌊kA⌋)⌋`, where `N,k∈Z`.

**Division method**:`f(k)=k mod N` where `N,k∈Z`?

A disadvantage of division method is the fact that possibility is higher to get same hash value if `N = 2^p, p>=0, p∈Z` as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797488/12980888) explained. How that is avoided please in Multiplication method?

Why the possibility to get same image using multiplication method (value of hashing that `k` is mapped to) is very low compared to division method hash function `f(k)=k mod N` please?

Comment: @NicoHaase. Thanks, but the post in the question is also the same. So my question based on that question.

Comment: The question should be asked on [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @Olivier. Thank you.